# How to use closure in this case?

Tags: javascript, closures

Look at `onComplete` results: currently `item.name` is always `rty`, but should be (1/2): `qwe`, (2/2): `rty`. I understand that this issue can be solved by using closure, but don't know how.

A little **update** http://jsfiddle.net/tJYem/

```
Items = function(){
    this.onProgress = function(current, total, item){};
    this.onComplete = function(){};
}

Items.prototype.add = function(items){

    var self = this;
    var i = 0, total = items.length;

    while(items.length){
        var item = items.shift();
        var img = new Image();

        // closure should be somewhere here...
        img.onload = function(){

            self.onProgress(++i, total, item);

            i == total && self.onComplete();

        }

        img.src = item.src;

    }

}


var items = new Items();

items.onProgress = function(current, total, item){
    console.log('(%d/%d) item `%s` loaded', current, total, item.name);
    // => (1/2) item `rty` loaded
    // => (2/2) item `rty` loaded
}

items.onComplete = function(){
    console.log('Loading items complete.')
}

items.add([
    {name: 'qwe', src: '../qwe.png'},
    {name: 'rty', src: '../rty.png'}
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `i` to be incremented by all `onload` handlers, so don't create a closure for that variable. Otherwise, all handlers would increment their own `i` instead of sharing the value. Also, `self` is independent of the images. However, `item` should be different in each handler: http://jsfiddle.net/tJYem/1/.

```
img.onload = (function(item){
    return function(){
        self.onProgress(++i, total, item);
        i == total && self.onComplete();
    }
})(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img.onload = (function(currentI) {
    // here currentI will stay with the value the i had in the moment of creating this handler
})(i)
```

Another thing to notice that in your logic `onComplete` handler is fired when the *last image from the list* is loaded, but not when *all of the images have loaded*.

Comment: do i need to pass all vars to closure? (i, total, item) ?

Comment: no, you only have to pass vars that can be changed by outside code, to "freeze" them

Comment: So, (meaning your notice about logic), how i could do it right?

Comment: If you use code from pimvdb's answer, you should be fine with it, because there i is incremented only in onload handler thus becoming the counter of loaded items.